# How can I find the current edit slide in PowerPoint?

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

I'm writing an add-in for PowerPoint, and want to get the text from the current slide in the editing window. The following works, but only when the slide is selected in the slide selector pane.

```
xSelection := PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection;
if xSelection.Type = ppSelectionSlides then
begin
  xSlide := xSelection.SlideRange.Item(1);
end;
```

I've been chasing my tail at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220907(v=office.11).aspx) trying to work out what the correct way to find out the current slide is. The DocumentWindow doesn't seem to have a current slide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at

ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

This link is useful http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163194

Comment: Many thanks. I don't actually need to go all the way to the SlideIndex - the slide object is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: This article, which has been flagged as retired, contains an inaccuracy: slide view is not the only view in which this property is valid. It is also valid, at least, for normal view, notes view, and slide sorter view. In any case, this was helpful, thanks.